# Ability to scope media queries or screen size to element

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, media-queries, responsive

I think the simplest way to explain the question is with an example.

Say I have some interactive builder that allows users to drag and move elements etc.. as well as apply certain predefined styles. These styles are responsive and will use media queries of the type `screen and (min-width: 768px)` as an example.

Then in the app I would like to provide a preview element that can be resized, very similar to chrome or any browser mobile preview. So I've been looking for a way to somehow override either the screen size or media query for all styles applied to elements that descendants of that preview element.

I hope that's clear enough. So far I've seen something about CSS container queries but wasn't quite able to confirm whether that would work in this case. To clarify, these same styles, are styles that I would like to then work anywhere else, even outside of this preview.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: How about using an `iframe` ?

Comment: @UmbQbify yes that's pretty good thanks, think may have too many issues with  dragging into / out of the iframe and events in general. Passing data through some api maybe a bit limiting for now.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you'll have to manually transform the css to suit your needs, Resize Observer could help with that